# Stop form input overflow scrolling div contents

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I have an input field within a absolute positioned div. The div has a specific width and overflow: hidden; applied with the input field being partially outside the confines of the container.

The problem arises in when typing in, the browser Firefox (and Chrome as well) will scroll the contents of this container div to make sure the input focus is within the viewport.

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px fuchsia solid;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;

  label {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
  }
  input {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

How can I stop it doing this? The above example is on:

https://codepen.io/meep3d/pen/jdLdqV

Comment: Ouch. It's doing it no matter what the position of `input` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get this done using JavaScript by setting `scrollLeft` to `0` on the scrollevent:

```js
document.getElementById('overlay').onscroll = function(){
  document.getElementById('overlay').scrollLeft = 0;
};
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px fuchsia solid;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
} 
label {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}
input {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
Outside

<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <label>Test Area</label>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that is a nasty as hell solution. It might just work :)

Comment: @Meep3D Yep nasty as hell! 

Comment: Needs must I suppose.